Optaplanner - Incrementally Calculate Justifications
In my application there is a need for users to be able to manually override the schedule and I would like to pre-calculate hard constraint matches so this process can be more efficient.
For example, in the course timetabling problem I have an existing schedule, and would like to generate additional potential lectures that a teacher could sign up for manually. Each potential lecture should be validated against the existing plan and its violations should be presented to the user (e.g. "you can't schedule at this time in this room because there is another lecture for the same curriculum in this period").
Our constraint streams have custom justifications that allow us to generate user-readable violation messages. But the way we're evaluating each lecture is inefficient. We create a SolutionManager, then for each potential lecture, make a new PlanningSolution object and tell the SolutionManager to explain it. This will result in the SolutionManager re-calculating many constraints for the existing schedule, rather than just the ones for the new potential lecture.
Note, if needed, we may be able to drop the requirement to display user-readable constraint violation messages. In that case, we wouldn't need the full justification map, we would just need the re-evaluated score to determine if the hard score got worse (we'd be returning a boolean isValidLecture rather than a String violationMessage).
All of this calculation is happening outside of a solver instance, is there a way to leverage incremental scoring so that we can make this more efficient?
We are currently using constraint streams with Bavet for score calculation. We are using Optaplanner version 9.37.Final.

Okay, to optimize evaluating potential lectures against your existing schedule, consider managing the state of PlanningSolution objects efficiently. Instead of creating new objects for each evaluation, make incremental changes to the existing solution. Optimize constraint streams to minimize redundant calculations. If user-readable violation messages aren't crucial, focus on evaluating whether each lecture violates hard constraints directly. Streamlining these processes can enhance efficiency for your users.

I know that when we use custom solving phases we need to trigger variable listeners to make sure all of the planning entities are up to date. Is there an equivalent that I need to do when using the Solution Manager? I am worried about score corruption by simply changing the solution and passing it back in

SolutionManager doesn't reuse anything from previous calculations, so you do not need to worry about score corruptions. As long as the solution is in correct state when passed to SolutionManager (incl. shadow variables), you will be fine. You may also want to look into SolutionManager.update(...) which can help you with shadow variables.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Our constraint streams have custom justifications that allow us to generate user-readable violation messages. But the way we're evaluating each lecture is inefficient. We create a SolutionManager, then for each potential lecture, make a new PlanningSolution object and tell the SolutionManager to explain it. This will result in the SolutionManager re-calculating many constraints for the existing schedule, rather than just the ones for the new potential lecture.

This is the intended way. You are correct that it is technically inefficient, but practically, it takes milliseconds, assuming your constraints are efficient.
If your constraints themselves are inefficient, that is your main problem and you should focus on solving that. Once solved, the entire issue goes away and as an extra benefit, your solver will be that much faster.

To give some more details, checking any one lecture takes milliseconds. But we are looking to pre-validate thousands or tens of thousands of lectures and want to optimize the process. Similarly to how solving performs thousands of scoring operations quickly using incremental scoring, I am interested in if I can perform my pre-validation more efficiently by reducing repeated calculations.

Using internal APIs, you should be able to reuse ScoreDirector instances and through before/afterVariable changes modify the solution between individual calls to calculate score. That is precisely what the solver does to be incremental. That said, I'm not going to tell you to use internal APIs, because those change often and without warning.
